# Fixed Points of Small Permutation Groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Given a subgroup $G\leq S_p$, where $p$ is prime, $|G|<p$, can we guarantee that the action of $G$ on $\{1,\ldots,p\}$ has a fixed point?

Comment: A fixed point of the action is a point fixed by all $g \in G$, right? Then we can't. Partition the set $\{1, \dotsc, p\}$ into sets with $2$ or $3$ elements each. The corresponding permutation has order $6$ (if $p > 3$), and no fixed point. So for $p \geqslant 7$ there's a $G$ of order $6 < p$ without fixed point.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p \leqslant 5$, every subgroup $G$ of $S_p$ with $\lvert G\rvert < p$ has a fixed point, as one can easily verify by considering all candidate subgroups.

For $p \geqslant 7$ this is not the case, there always is a $G$ of order $6$ that acts without fixed point, for example the cyclic subgroup generated by the fixed-point-free permutation
$$(1,2,3)(4,5)\ldots (p-1,p)\,.$$